Changing the mouse-pointer size inside of Emacs
I encountered an interesting problem: my mouse curser (Arrow, PointingHand, Bar... Symbol) got scaled in spite of the font staying the same size.
https://imgur.com/a/FfYypba
I'm running Windows 11 with WSL2 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
I researched and tried

changing the cursor size through gsettings: 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size XX
resetting font size in Emacs
playing around with the Cursor Types within Emacs (Frame default, filled box, box with specific size...)

Nothing worked so far.

You don't say how or when or in what context it "got changed". Did it change in Emacs? Did it also stay changed outside Emacs? Not much to go on, to help, by maybe someone will be able to.
